# Light fixture in basement with a light switch that has an outlet next to it ........light won't work now

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I recently replaced my light fixture in the basement.

The second time I flipped it on, it made a buzzing noise and went out.

When I do a wire test, the light outlet wires are getting no power. At the light box switch the outlet is getting power but the switch isn't.

The black wire from one set goes to the switch and the other wire hooked to it is another black bridging wire to the plug in the outlet.

and hooks he the side white and all which ones are hooked to the the back side of the plugin.

No ground on the switch but there's one on the plugin outlet. No ground on light fixture as well.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your description is very confusing and I can't tell what is connected to what. - However sometimes it's possible to fix a problem without understanding every detail of the circuit. Are the wires connected to the outlet and switch by being wrapped around screw terminals, or are they pushed into holes in the backs of the devices? Are there any wire nuts in the switch box?

Comment: When you replaced the light fixture, did you do any work at all in the switch box?

Comment: How did you do the "wire test"? Do you have a meter? Can you do a continuity test?

Comment: I agree with the comments above, to help you we need it to be reworded. Please indicate: "I have a switch, an outlet, and a light fixture"; the outlet and the fixture are controlled by the switch... or what is controlled by the switch, then explain what is working and what is not, as well as what you modified/repaired already

Comment: OK so in this room there is a switch with one set of wires and only the black one went through the hole in it and another black one in the other hole and is hooked to the outlet

Comment: by being wrapped around the screw terminals the ground is cut short and not grounded ...... Now on to the outlet the wire from the switch is connected to the top screw but its on the side that says white ....... There are two more sets of .wires that connect to the out let as follows the two black ones are on the the other screw terminal on the bottom one one

Comment: the white side then the grounds are grounded to the screw terminal below that ......then the white ones are connected by the one from the switch to the bottom  black side with one of the white ones from the other set on the screw terminal and the one  from the other wire sets is on the top screw terminal on the white side .......now to the light therapy are the black and white that come out of the box and thats the set that has the ground cut short..... The original light fixture was a single 660w/250v  the one my friend put up was a fixture with two 660w /250v socket light ony

Comment: black and white connected not grounded... It  worked then made noise and this is where I'm at.....When I wire test them the black one from the switch and the white one s from either sets nothing but all the other ones light up......

Comment: EDIT the original question so it is clear, don't bother adding it in comments. Please answer how you are performing the wire test.  What are you using, and what are you connecting to. Please also describe If the switch is currently turning either the light or outlet on and off, and also tell us if the switch used to contro both the light and the outlet? Also, what country are you in since you are saying 660w/250v?

Answer (score 0):

If you replaced a light fixture and when you turned it on it started to buzz then went out. Then let's go tho the obvious. You had a short in the wiring at the fixture. **So first turn off the breaker to the fixture.** Remove the fixture and look inside your box. I am guessing that you will find a wire burnt in half or at a splice or it may be wired incorrectly. If that fixture has a ballast or driver you can assume that the miss wiring has burnt it out and needs replacing.

You said you had a wire coming from the receptacle to the switch. You say the a conductor is coming from the receptacle and it didn't trip the breaker. I am assuming that would be your hot. Check the switch by using a continuity tester touch both posts of the switch and see if you can get it to ring when you turn the switch on.

You also run a ground to the switch and connect the fixture to the ground to eliminate a possible shock hazard.

Good luck and stay safe.

Comment: The part about the continuity tests, in a separate paragaph also require the breaker being turned off. In fact, the entire write-up says to turn the breaker off, but assumes you leave it off.

Comment: It could also be a failed ballast that caused the problem high current causing a back stab failure at a back stab ?

Comment: OK so in this room there is a switch with one set of wires and only the black one went through the hole in it and another black one in the other hole and is hooked to the outlet

Comment: by being wrapped around the screw terminals the ground is cut short and not grounded ...... Now on to the outlet the wire from the switch is connected to the top screw but its on the side that says white ....... There are two more sets of .wires that connect to the out let as follows the two black ones are on the the other screw terminal on the bottom one one

Comment: the white side then the grounds are grounded to the screw terminal below that ......then the white ones are connected by the one from the switch to the bottom  black side with one of the white ones from the other set on the screw terminal and the one  from the other wire sets is on the top screw terminal on the white side .......now to the light therapy are the black and white that come out of the box and thats the set that has the ground cut short..... The original light fixture was a single 660w/250v  the one my friend put up was a fixture with two 660w /250v socket light ony

Comment: black and white connected not grounded... It  worked then made noise and this is where I'm at.....When I wire test them the black one from the switch and the white one s from either sets nothing but all the other ones light up......