# Light fixture with a switch that has an outlet

Tags: electrical

I hope this explains it better: in this room there is a switch with one set of wires and only the black one went through the hole in it, and another black one in the other hole, and is hooked to the outlet by being wrapped around the screw terminals. The ground is cut short and not grounded.

Now on to the outlet: the wire from the switch is connected to the top screw - but it's on the side that says "white".

There are two more sets of wires that connect to the outlet as follows:

- the two black ones are on the the other screw terminal on the bottom (one on the "white" side)
- the grounds are grounded to the screw terminal below that
- the white ones are connected by the one from the switch to the bottom (black side), with one of the white ones from the other set on the screw terminal, and the one from the other cable is on the top screw terminal on the "white" side.

Now to the light: there are the black and white that come out of the box, and that is the set that has the ground cut short.

The original light fixture was a single 660w/250v rated socket.  The one my friend put up was a fixture with two 660w /250v sockets.  At the light only black and white connected, not ground... It worked then made noise and this is where I'm at.

When I wire test them, the black one from the switch and the white ones from either sets nothing...  but all the other ones light up.....!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Light fixture in basement with a light switch that has an outlet next to it ........light won't work now](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122020/light-fixture-in-basement-with-a-light-switch-that-has-an-outlet-next-to-it)

Comment: Good pic.  Right off the bat, the receptacle is wired backwards.  The side with the taller blade (left if the ground pin is down)  is neutral, or white.

Comment: So which of these two questions should we be answering? Kristina, pick one and delete the other or mark it duplicate. Please answer the questions being asked so we can safely help you. We are not there so to actually give you the answer safely, we need to understand a few things. This one picture helps. A picture of the switch and light would probably be a good idea. So you know, the 660W/250V is just a rating, its not what you are actually using at that fixture. The BLACK wire should be HOT. so the light switch should DEFINITELY have a BLACK wire in it, ideally, it has two black wires.

Comment: Please confirm: does your switch have two BLACK wires? if so, are you using an AC detector (light )to test the power? You still haven;t told us what you are testing with. Please be safe, be careful, and if you can help us, we can help you.